# Empty Mysql field (NULL) ends up being a string "null" in Java

Tags: java, php, json

I have some data extracted from a MySQL database where some fields are *NULL*. Not accidentally as a string but properly stored as *NULL*. When I send these null-data JSON-encoded to my android app, they end up being a string "null" of length 4. So I rebuilt this problem condensed to the essential code:

PHP:

```
$string = null;
echo $array[0]['alt_names'] = $string;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Java: (My PHP class returns a string, in this case `jsonResult`)

```
Log.i("Tag", "result = " + jsonResult);          // result = [{"alt_names":null}]

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
Log.i("Tag", "jsonArray = " + jsonArray);        // jsonArray = [{"alt_names":null}]

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString());
Log.i("Tag", "jsonobject = " + jsonObject);      // jsonobject = {"alt_names":null}

String test = jsonObject.get("alt_names").toString();
Log.i("Tag", "test: " + test);                   // test: null
Log.i("Tag", "test.length(): " + test.length()); // test.length(): 4
```

The missing quotation marks (not) enclosing `null` in the Log-output show me, that this is not a string "null" butt actually `null`. Nevertheless the string's length is 4 and this is true:

```
if (test.equals("null")) {Log.i("Tag", "true");} // true
```

What do I not understand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: String test = jsonObject.get("alt_names").toString(); <- you are casting it to string here...

Comment: If I don't I get the error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String".

Comment: If you just want to check for a null-value, you could also use jsonObject.isNull()...

Comment: Well... That seems to work, but it means that I'll have to add about ten if-statements, which I find (sorry) really ugly. (`$array[0]` contains a lot of strings). But as I don't see any other solution for this, I thank you and use this until I come across the proper way to get my string out of my jsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a `toString()` on the object return by `jsonObject.get("alt_names")`. It is actually the static instance of [JSONObject.NULL](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL)

```
Object test = jsonObject.get("alt_names");
System.out.println(test == JSONObject.NULL); // true
System.out.println(test.equals(null)); // true
System.out.println(jsonObject.isNull("alt_names")); // true
```

From javadoc :

> It is sometimes more convenient and less ambiguous to have a NULL object than to use Java's null value. JSONObject.NULL.equals(null) returns true. JSONObject.NULL.toString() returns "null".